# Artinian module and short exact sequence

Tags: modules, noetherian

Consider the short exact sequence of modules

$$0\rightarrow M\rightarrow N\rightarrow K\rightarrow0$$
Let $K$ be an Artinian (Noetherian) module, can we get $N$ is an Artinian (Noetherian) module?

Comment: $K$ could be the zero module, and $M \cong N$, so it seems you'll need more assumptions than this.

Answer (score 2):

The result, as concerns short exact sequences, is that $N$ is artinian if and only if $M$  and $K$  are artinian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bernard. I knew that, now I wanted to see have been thinking on this subject with this condition until now?

Comment: @Sara: I don't quite understand what your question is?